# UrlFetchApp Variable Errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, http-get, urlfetch

I'm trying to make a proxy with the UrlFetchApp Google Scripts API. However, with a query string of `?url="https://google.com"`, it gives me this error:

```
Exception: Invalid argument: "https://google.com" (line 3, file "Code")
```

But when I substitute `param` in my code below for https://google.com, the exact value of param, it works perfectly fine for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var param = e["parameter"]["url"];
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(param);
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: How about `e.parameter.url`?

Comment: @Cooper When I do that, it shows this error message: `Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url (line 3, file "Code")`

Comment: The problem is the quotation marks in your querystring as Tanaike has pointed out

Comment: @Cooper Yep, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

I think that in your Web Apps script, the double quotes are not required.

#### From:

```
?url="https://google.com"
```

#### To:

```
?url=https://google.com
```

or, when the URL encode is used, it becomes as follows.

```
?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```